# Preventing keyboard shortcuts being triggered in QScintilla (example code)

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts, pyqt, qscintilla

I would like to prevent application keyboard shortcuts from being triggered when editing code in my QScintilla widget, just like a normal QLineEdit field doesn't.

In the executable example code below it is not possible to type whitespaces in the QScintilla widget because the spacebar has been set as a shortcut, but in the QLineEdit it works properly.

I wonder if it could be something to do with the QScintilla not grabbing keyboard input properly (though it obviously does, since it is possible to input characters in it).

```
import sys,os
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import Qsci

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.butt = QPushButton("button!!")       
        self.act = QAction("new act",self)
        self.act.setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Space))
        self.act.triggered.connect(tjosan)
        self.butt.clicked.connect(self.act.trigger)
        self.sci = Qsci.QsciScintilla()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()    
        vbox.addWidget(self.sci)
        vbox.addWidget(QLineEdit())
        vbox.addWidget(self.butt)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.addAction(self.act)

def tjosan():
    print "action !!!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widg = MyWidget()
    widg.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter ShortcutOverride events to get the same behaviour as QLineEdit. Here's an edited version of your example that demonstrates a way to do that:

```
import sys,os
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import Qsci

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.butt = QPushButton("button!!")
        self.act = QAction("new act",self)
        self.act.setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Space))
        self.act.triggered.connect(tjosan)
        self.butt.clicked.connect(self.act.trigger)
        self.sci = Qsci.QsciScintilla()
        self.sci.installEventFilter(self)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.sci)
        vbox.addWidget(QLineEdit())
        vbox.addWidget(self.butt)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.addAction(self.act)

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if (event.type() == QEvent.ShortcutOverride and
            widget is self.sci):
            print 'ShortcutOverride'
            event.accept()
            return True
        return QWidget.eventFilter(self, widget, event)

def tjosan():
    print "action !!!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widg = MyWidget()
    widg.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That works beautifully! Thanks a lot.
My hackish interim solution was to disable the  shortcuts in focusInEvent(), which worked but had an odor to it.