# Ctrl+U key combination lost when porting from Qt4 to Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm in the process of porting a program from Qt4 to Qt5. I got it to the point where it compiles with both versions. Almost everything seems to work in the new version, excepted that I have lost the `Ctrl+U` keyboard shortcut in the Qt5 version in two different contexts:

- in a dialog box, using a `QShortcut` assigned to the `Ctrl+U` key sequence
- in the main window, when listening for evens in an event filter.

This seems specific to `Ctrl+U`. I know that in the dialog box, other shortcuts like `Ctrl+F` or `Ctrl+W` work as they used to, and that in the main window, `Ctrl+P` works as before too.

Is there anything special about `Ctrl+U` (and possibly others) in Qt5 that prevent me from seeing the event ?

**Edit**

It seems it is linked to the presence of a line edit. MWE:

```
#include "mw.hh"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QShortcut>
#include <QStatusBar>
#include <QKeySequence>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QLineEdit>


static void registerShortCut(const QKeySequence & seq, QWidget * receiver, 
                             const char * fn,
                             Qt::ShortcutContext context = Qt::WindowShortcut)
{
  QShortcut * sc = new QShortcut(seq, receiver);
  sc->setContext(context);
  receiver->connect(sc, SIGNAL(activated()), fn);
}

MW::MW()
{
  statusBar()->showMessage("stuff");
  registerShortCut(QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+T")),
                   this, SLOT(test()));
  registerShortCut(QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+U")),
                   this, SLOT(test2()));

  QLineEdit * le = new QLineEdit("stuff");
  setCentralWidget(le);
}

void MW::test()
{
  statusBar()->showMessage("Test !");
}

void MW::test2()
{
  statusBar()->showMessage("Test 2 !");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  QApplication main(argc, argv);
  MW mw;
  mw.show();
  main.exec();
}
```

With `mw.hh`:

```
#include <QMainWindow>

class MW : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT;
public:
  MW();

public slots:
  void test();
  void test2();
};
```

Hitting `Ctrl+T` shows Test in the status bar, but `Ctrl+U` does not. Commenting out the `setCentralWidget(le)` line restores the expected behaviour.

Comment: Do you get any log messages that says the shortcut is defined multiple times? If that happens, the shortcut is disabled altogether; neither place where it's assigned will work.

Comment: @goug No, I don't have any of those. Moreover, in one of the two cases, I'm not using a shortcut, just intercepting events.

Comment: It sounds like something higher up is intercepting Ctrl-U before it gets to your application or your dialog. Is Ctrl-U a shortcut on the dialog's system menu, or something along those lines? (You haven't said what platform you're on.) Do you run both the Qt4 version and the Qt5 version on the same box, but get these different results?

Comment: @goug Platform is Linux; both versions are run in the exact same environment.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the source of the problem, especially since `Ctrl+U` is not referenced as keyboard shortcut in [QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html). However, I found a nice workaround, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719806/preventing-keyboard-shortcuts-being-triggered-in-qscintilla-example-code). I added the following code to my own subclass of `QApplication`:

```
  bool notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event) 
  {
    // We override keyboard shortcuts within QLineEdit
    if(event->type() == QEvent::ShortcutOverride &&
       dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(receiver)) {
      event->ignore();
      return false;
    }
    return QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
  }
```