# How to assign QScintilla shortcuts

Tags: python, pyqt, keyboard-shortcuts, pyqt5, qscintilla

I'm trying to implement shortcuts to my editor, but I haven't had any success so far.

I'd like to override some of the default QScintilla shortcuts. I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719806/preventing-keyboard-shortcuts-being-triggered-in-qscintilla-example-code), but I'm not sure if this helps to solve my problem.

I have also read the [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#keyDefinition) (`SCI_ASSIGNCMDKEY`) documentation, but I don't know how I'm supposed to use it in a pythonic way.

To make it clear:

1. I'd like to override the QScintilla shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> and use my custom solution (assign it to one of my functions).
2. I'd like to assign the command `SCI_LINEDELETE` to the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

This is my idea:

```
    from PyQt5.Qsci import QsciScintilla
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    import sys

    class mainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent = None):
            super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):
            self.center_window = centerWindow(parent=self)
            self.setCentralWidget(self.center_window) 

    class centerWindow(QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(centerWindow, self).__init__(parent)

            self.hhEditor_te = QsciScintilla()

            vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
            vbox.addWidget(self.hhEditor_te)
            self.setLayout(vbox)

            # 1)
            # assign a key binding to this function
            # self.my_shortcut

            # 2)
            # assign a key binding to the QScintilla command
            # SCI_LINEDELETE

        def my_shortcut(self):
            pass
            # my custom shortcut function

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication.instance()
        if app is None:
            app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        else:
            print('QApplication instance already exists: %s' % str(app))

        ex = mainWindow()
        ex.setGeometry(0,100,1500,600)
        ex.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QScintilla already provides the [QsciCommandSet](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciCommandSet.html) and [QsciCommand](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciCommand.html) classes for handling shortcuts for the internal editor commands. You can also use [QShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html) to create shortcuts for your own methods.

```
class centerWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        commands = self.hhEditor_te.standardCommands()

        command = commands.boundTo(Qt.ControlModifier | Qt.Key_L)
        if command is not None:
            command.setKey(0) # clear the default
        command = commands.boundTo(Qt.ControlModifier | Qt.Key_D)
        if command is not None:
            command.setKey(0) # clear the default

        command = commands.find(QsciCommand.LineDelete)
        if command is not None:
            command.setKey(Qt.ControlModifier | Qt.Key_D)

        shortcut = QShortcut(Qt.ControlModifier | Qt.Key_L, self.hhEditor_te)
        shortcut.activated.connect(self.my_shortcut)
        ...

    def my_shortcut(self):
        print('Ctrl+L')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a toolbar in your QScintilla, action shortcuts is as followeded

```
self.toolBar.newAction = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(":/ico/new.png"),"New",self.toolBar)
self.toolBar.newAction.setStatusTip("Clear TextBox or make new document.")
self.toolBar.newAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
self.toolBar.newAction.triggered.connect(self.newfile)

    #actions
self.toolBar.addAction(self.toolBar.newAction)
self.toolBar.addSeparator()
```